# How can I shift the text of a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, text-decorations

I'm using tikz to represent an axe. The code is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{longtable,geometry}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\geometry{dvips,a4paper,margin=1in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.footprints}
\MakeAutoQuote{«}{»}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,>=stealth,->] (0,0) node[below] {$-\infty$} --  (2.8,0) node[below]  
{$\frac{\mathlarger{-e}}{\mathlarger{(1-\theta)}}-f$} node {$\bullet$} -- (5.6,0)
node[below] {$\frac{\mathlarger{-v}}{\mathlarger{(1-\theta)}}-f$} node {$\bullet$} --
(8.4,0) node[below] {$\frac{-2f-e-\sqrt{e^2-\frac{4ev}{1-\theta)}}}{2}$} node 
{$\bullet$} -- (11.4,0) node[below] {$\frac{-2f-e+\sqrt{e^2-\frac{4ev}
{1-\theta)}}}{2}$} node {$\bullet$} -- (14.2,0) node[below] {$-f$} node{$\bullet$}-- 
(17,0) node[below] {$\omega(M)$} ;

\draw[color=black,decorate,decoration={brace, raise=0.8cm}]
(0,0) -- (5.57,0) node[above,pos=0.5] {E1};

\draw[color=black,decorate,decoration={brace, raise=0.8cm}]
(5.63,0) -- (8.37,0) node[above,pos=0.5] {E1, E2};

\draw[color=black,decorate,decoration={brace, raise=0.8cm}]
(8.43,0) -- (11.37,0) node[above,pos=0.5] {E1, E2, E3};

\draw[color=black,decorate,decoration={brace, raise=0.8cm}]
(11.43,0) -- (14.17,0) node[above,pos=0.5] {E1, E2};

\draw[color=black,decorate,decoration={brace, raise=0.8cm}]
(14.23,0) -- (16.7,0) node[above,pos=0.5] {E2};

\draw[color=red,decorate,decoration={brace, mirror, raise=1.5cm}]
(0,0) -- (2.77,0) node[below,pos=0.49] {E5};

\draw[color=red,decorate,decoration={brace, mirror, raise=1.5cm}]
(2.83,0) -- (17,0) node[below,pos=0.5] {E4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

How can I move the text E4 and E5 for it to be closer to the red brace?

Thanks in advance, and sorry if the layout is not the right one.

Comment: I don't quite get the question but can you try using `below=1cm` in the `E4` and `E5` nodes?

Answer (score 7):

The `below` key takes an optional distance argument. Setting `below=1.6cm` works quite well in this case.

Note that you don't need to load the `xcolors` package explicitly (this is done by `tikz`) or the `decorations` library (it's loaded by the specific decorations libraries), and you have a lot of packages in your code that aren't needed for this example.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,>=stealth,->] (0,0) node[below] {$-\infty$} --  (2.8,0) node[below]  
{$\frac{\mathlarger{-e}}{\mathlarger{(1-\theta)}}-f$} node {$\bullet$} -- (5.6,0) node[below] {$\frac{\mathlarger{-v}}{\mathlarger{(1-\theta)}}-f$} node {$\bullet$} -- (8.4,0) node[below] {$\frac{-2f-e-\sqrt{e^2-\frac{4ev}{1-\theta)}}}{2}$} node {$\bullet$} -- (11.4,0) node[below] {$\frac{-2f-e+\sqrt{e^2-\frac{4ev}{1-\theta)}}}{2}$} node {$\bullet$} -- (14.2,0) node[below] {$-f$} node{$\bullet$}-- (17,0) node[below] {$\omega(M)$} ;

\draw[color=black,decorate,decoration={brace, raise=0.8cm}]
(0,0) -- (5.57,0) node[above=0.8cm,pos=0.5] {E1};

\draw[color=black,decorate,decoration={brace, raise=0.8cm}]
(5.63,0) -- (8.37,0) node[above=0.8cm,pos=0.5] {E1, E2};

\draw[color=black,decorate,decoration={brace, raise=0.8cm}]
(8.43,0) -- (11.37,0) node[above=0.8cm,pos=0.5] {E1, E2, E3};

\draw[color=black,decorate,decoration={brace, raise=0.8cm}]
(11.43,0) -- (14.17,0) node[above=0.8cm,pos=0.5] {E1, E2};

\draw[color=black,decorate,decoration={brace, raise=0.8cm}]
(14.23,0) -- (16.7,0) node[above=0.8cm,pos=0.5] {E2};

\draw[color=red,decorate,decoration={brace, mirror, raise=1.5cm}]
(0,0) -- (2.77,0) node[below=1.6cm,pos=0.49] {E5};

\draw[color=red,decorate,decoration={brace, mirror, raise=1.5cm}]
(2.83,0) -- (17,0) node[below=1.6cm,pos=0.5] {E4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I know for the package but this is just a part of my document. I also have trees, some other graphs and all my master dissertation...Anyway, thanks again for your help and advices!

Comment: @Juliette don't forget to upvote Jake's answer, and if it solved your problem, click the green check mark; this gives Jake 25 reputation points and is the best way to say thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a touch of style! (I took the code of Jake's fine answer)

remark : (a) -- node {x} (b); by default pos=.5
update : a lot of node use `below`so I modify `every node/.style`but to adjust other nodes, I created `ce/.style={anchor=center}`. `below` is the same option than `anchor=south`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[bst/.style={color=black,decorate,decoration={brace, raise=0.8cm}},
                    rst/.style={color=red,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror, raise=1.5cm}},
                    eti/.style={above=0.8cm},
                    every node/.style=below,
                    ce/.style={anchor=center}] 

\draw[thick,>=stealth,->] (0,0) 
  node     {$-\infty$}   -- (2.8,0)  node {$\frac{\mathlarger{-e}}{\mathlarger{(1-\theta)}}-f$} 
  node[ce] {$\bullet$}   -- (5.6,0)  node {$\frac{\mathlarger{-v}}{\mathlarger{(1-\theta)}}-f$} 
  node[ce] {$\bullet$}   -- (8.4,0)  node {$\frac{-2f-e-\sqrt{e^2-\frac{4ev}{1-\theta)}}}{2}$}  
  node[ce] {$\bullet$}   -- (11.4,0) node {$\frac{-2f-e+\sqrt{e^2-\frac{4ev}{1-\theta)}}}{2}$}  
  node[ce] {$\bullet$}   -- (14.2,0) node {$-f$} 
  node[ce] {$\bullet$}   -- (17,0)   node {$\omega(M)$} ;

\draw[bst] (0,0)     -- node[eti]          {E1}         (5.57 ,0) ;
\draw[bst] (5.63,0)  -- node[eti]          {E1, E2}     (8.37 ,0) ;
\draw[bst] (8.43,0)  -- node[eti]          {E1, E2, E3} (11.37,0) ;
\draw[bst] (11.43,0) -- node[eti]          {E1, E2}     (14.17,0) ;
\draw[bst] (14.23,0) -- node[eti]          {E2}         (16.7 ,0) ;
\draw[rst] (0,0)     -- node[below=1.6cm]  {E5}         (2.77 ,0) ;
\draw[rst] (2.83,0)  -- node[below=1.6cm]  {E4}         (17   ,0) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```